# UART protocol in android studio

Tags: java, android, uart

i have to develop a simple android app using android studio and java.

For my app i have to read the values of the light sensor of the mobile phone and then i have to use the UART protocol to receive these values and then to store them in relation to the value read.
At the beginning, for example, if the value is 50.0 lux or greater this app has to store 1, 0 otherwise.

I use SensorManager and EventListener to read the values of the light sensor but i don't know how to continue. In particular i don't know how to implement the UART protocol and how to use it so that it reads the values and then it does the right operations with them.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: UART is a hardware protocol for serial connections, so you need a serial connector. So you can not "implement" UART, you just have to use the correct hardware and connect to that hardware.

Comment: @Robert yeah but in my case i have to simulate this type of connection, because i need that the app takes the values and then, with UART, stores them for a subsequent encoding.

Comment: So this question is about adding start/stop bits and parity bits to a data stream (e.g. a TCP stream)?

Comment: Maybe yes, but i don't know if it's similar. Sorry but i'm very new in this area.

Comment: Your post makes no sense. If your app has already "*read the values of the light sensor*", then why does your app have to "*use the UART protocol to receive these values*" again? No, you do not "*add start/stop bits and parity bits*" in software; that is performed by UART hardware (unless you intend to bit-bang the data).